# When I try to open System Preferences from the dock it opens directly into the iCloud pane

Tags: icloud

I would like to open directly to the System Preferences pane, but instead it diverts to the iCloud pane. I have tried deleting the Users>Library>Preferences>.com.apple.desktop.plist file, but this doesn't exist--instead I only see .com.apple.dock.plist. Will this do just as well to delete?

Answer (score 11):

Does System Preferences have a badge (red 1) on it? This might indicate that iCloud is prompting you to turn on two-factor authentication. If that is the case, go to System Preferences > iCloud > and where it says “Two-factor authentication” click Continue to the right of it and then select your preferences.

For screenshots of this process and more discussion of it, see [Apple Discussions – “System Preferences Dock Icon has red circle with 1”](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7906794).

> [image: Two-Factor Authentication setup sheet after clicking “Continue” in iCloud preferences]

I would recommend doing research into [two-factor authentication](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915) or [two-step verification](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204152) before turning it on. It is a high level of security that comes with greater responsibility for you to go through the steps to validate trusted devices – all of which use iCloud and need manual steps.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. When I enter the iCloud part of System Preferences, the only option I have is to enter my  Apple ID password to continue to iCloud--however, when I do this (and it is the correct password), the system keeps on spinning indefinitely. IN short, there is no option I can enter once I get into the iCloud part of System Preferences at present.

Comment: I was always afraid to click “Continue” in the iCloud preferences in case that turned on the two-factor authentication immediately. But now I know **it’s safe to click “Continue”**: it just opens a sheet where you can choose whether to “Turn On”, “Learn More”, or “Not Now”. Choosing “Not Now” dismisses the notification without having turn on 2FA.